# Why does my regular user have the same permissions as the admin user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this command in my views/welcome/index.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to 'Post New Load Data!', new_article_path %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

Earlier today, this would allow only my admin user to see this path.
I installed Devise a few hours ago but ended up not liking it.  So I have gone through and removed what I thought was every file that it created.

Earlier, if I wanted a regular user to see the path, I would use...

```
<% if current_user %>
```

instead of

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
```

I don't if that is what is creating my problem.  My migrations did get messed up so I had to reset everything and I created new migration under db/migrate/20161209013349_create_users.rb:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :admin, :boolean, null: false, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I checked my MySQL users table and the non admin user has a 0 under the admin column.  My admin user has as 1 under the admin column.  There is a 0 under the boolean column for both regular user and admin.

my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to '/login' unless current_user
  end

end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    if User.exists?(email: params[:user][:email])
      redirect_to '/articles?user_or_pass_already_exists'
    else
      user = User.new(user_params)
      if user.save
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to '/'
      else
        redirect_to '/signup'
      end
    end
end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Any ideas on what caused this?

I think it's the way I set up this model.

*EDIT*

I also created this method for my admin in /app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  # convienience method to access the vaulue of admin:
  def admin?
    admin
  end

  # this makes sure the same email and user can't be registered twice
  # this only works well if you are only wanting to validate one field such as name
#validates :email, uniqueness: true

end
```

This is why I am using admin? in my current_user.admin?

Comment: What actions are you talking about?

Comment: If I placed <% if current_user %> in a .html.erb, it would allow a general user to do whatever is needed.  If I placed <% if current_user.admin? %> in the .html.erb, it would not be visible to regular users.  Only the admin user could see this.  This should only allow the admin user to see a link on the index.html.erb that says "Post New Load Data!"                                                            <% if current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to 'Post New Load Data!', new_article_path %>
<% else %>
<% end %>

Comment: oops, didnt mean to post this

Comment: You must verify that links are not shown to people who can't use them, plus check on the controller side that people aren't making requests they shouldn't. It's always a two part verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You must understand that even If you hide links from user You need server side check (authorization) before every action. cancancan gem will help you.

Now, for your question,

```
def admin?
    admin
  end
```

This method will return value of `admin` column.

According to this line in your migration

```
t.string :admin, :boolean, null: false, default: false
```

My guess is column type of `admin` column in database is `string`. Where It should be of type `boolean`. All string values are true in ruby.

```
2.2.0 :004 > if "0"
2.2.0 :005?>   puts "I am true"
2.2.0 :006?>   end
(irb):6: warning: string literal in condition
I am true
```

So either change your column type to `boolean` or change your method in user.rb like this

```
def admin?
  admin == "1"
end
```